# Adding list element

Tags: java, algorithm, list

I have two lists containing:

`Result List: null`

`List2: { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, etc.}`

the result List is then:

`Result List: { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, etc.}`

`List2: { 2, 1,  3, 4, 6, 2, 1, etc.}`

then the `Result List` is:

`Result List: { 3, 3, 6, 8, 11, 8, 8, etc.}`

As you can see the list just adds element by element.

I tried to implement it simply by that:

```
ArrayList<Double> tempList = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int l = 0; l < entries.length; l++) {
    double result = resultList.get(l) + valueList.get(l);
    tempList.add(result);
    if(resultlist == null)  {
        resultList = templist;
    }
}
```

However that does not seem to work in java.

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: You're only setting resultList if it was null. But if it was null, you would have gotten a NullPointerException when calculating result. Reconsider your logic and try again.

Comment: What do you mean by _that does not seem to work_? Do you get any errors? Is the output not what you expected?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no results in `tempList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result are in `tempList` not in `resultlist` because of bug!

### Bug

Checking if `resultlist` is `null` has no sense.

```
double result = resultList.get(l) + valueList.get(l); // resultList is not null
tempList.add(result);
if(resultlist == null)  { // this is not needed, this is always not null
    resultList = templist; // never executed
}
```

### Solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Long> resultlist = Arrays.asList(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L);

    calculateList(resultlist, Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L));
    calculateList(resultlist, Arrays.asList(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L));

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultlist.toArray()));
}

private static void calculateList(List<Long> resultList, List<Long> input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
        resultList.set(i, resultList.get(i) + input.get(i));
    }
}
```

Result

```
 [3, 3, 6, 8, 11, 8]
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! Is there another way to implement that?

Comment: 3 minutes left dude... ;p Do not hurry!

Comment: btw do you have any suggestions for possible better implementation of the algorithm?

Comment: Im looking at it :) Give me more time too :D

Comment: Would be also interested in a possible solution!

Comment: @MariuszS yes that is other variable output from `List2`

Comment: No, `2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 1, ` is input data for this program

Answer (score -3):

Its better to start from an empty list instead of a null value.  I think that way your code will work

You can use something like this

```
if(resultList == null)
{
resultList = new ArrayList<Double>();
}
ArrayList<Double> tempList = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int l = 0; l < entries.length; l++) {
double result = valueList.get(l);
if(resultList.size()>l)
{
    result += resultList.get(l);
}
    tempList.add(result);
    if(resultlist == null)  {
        resultList = templist;
    }
}
```